# Can custom IHttpHandler revert to default request handling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-routing, ihttphandler

I'm writing a custom HttpHandler to process web requests for a web framework I'm writing but trying to find a way to programatically "ignore" the request if no url route is matched. What I mean by ignore is if no predefined route matches the incoming request url to then default to the standard request processing you would get if you were using a raw ASP.Net web application.

The only way I can find that actually works so far is to remove the custom http handler for a specific path, e.g.:

```
<location path="Test">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="DefaultHandler"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

I'm not massively satisfyed with this solution and would like to implement something akin to MVC's `IgnoreRoute("...")`. Digging through ths source though is a bit of a thankless task and I can't see where it's actually doing it.

So ideally I'd like to know if it's possible to somehow exit the custom http handler and let the application handle it in a default manner or find out how MVC does this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what HTTP handlers are for - HTTP handlers are for very specific URL formats, for example applying to every file with a given extension (a minifier for all `*.js` requests, a page handler for all `*.aspx` requests, an auto-resizer for all `*.jpg` requests...). If you want to work cooperatively with the other HTTP modules, you have to use a HTTP module - those are used for things like filtering, initialization, routing etc. You can change the executing HTTP handler, sure, but there's no "default" handler to switch to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in an Httphandler.

Consider using an HttpModule. This is also how MCV routing works.